# Split list content by "*\n" to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, wikipedia-api

I'm using beautiful soup to scrape some content from Wikipedia via the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, json

s = 'September%2011'
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={0}&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=1&format=xml&formatversion=2'.format(s)
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
content = r.text
events = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
events = [events.text for events in soup.find_all("rev")]
print(events)
```

The content are events which occurred on a particular day. On Wikipedia each event is displayed as a dotpoint, but from the API it comes out as a long list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=September%2011&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=1&format=xml&formatversion=2

I'd like to place the content into a dataframe, with a separate row for each event i.e. every time there is a "\n*".

I've looked at a few answers re list splits but can't figure out how to apply in this case.

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(events[0].split('\n*')[1:], columns=["Events"])
print(df)

Events
0   [[1185]] &ndash; [[Isaac II Angelos]] kills [[...
1   [[1226]] &ndash; The first recorded instance o...
2   [[1297]] &ndash; [[Battle of Stirling Bridge]]...
3   [[1390]] &ndash; [[Lithuanian Civil War (1389–...
...
```